# Symbol LS2208 running on Android

Tags: usb-peripherals

I try to use Symbol LS2208 (Barcode Scanner) with USB OTG on my Xperia Ray and nothing happen. I think my Xperia can use LS2208 because I using Logitect B100 (mouse) and work perfectly.

When I connect LS2208 into my Laptop with Windows 7 and UBuntu, LS2208 work perfect marked with beep.

Is there any driver for running LS2208 with Android?

Comment: What kind of USB device is this? Does it pretend to be a keyboard and type the barcode you scan, or is it a special purpose device?

Comment: I think that device like keyboard

Answer (score 0):

If this device acts as a USB keyboard, then you don't need a special driver. Just be sure to set everything up before you start scanning: start an app that has some text input, and make sure you focus the text input field as if you're about to type in it.